# JQuery, hide <li> and <ul> of menu, show only on hover

Tags: jquery, menu, hover, hide

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sUm2W/

This one is a little hard to explain so I've included all the code I am using.

When the page loads the li elements show until I hover over them, at which point they disappear and the menu works exactly as I want it to. What is making them visible? I have tried setting the li width to 0px but this doesn't work either.

Also, why is there a 40px border at the left hand side of the UL? I haven't made any borders yet in order for the text to show to the extreme left I need to set the li margin to -40px.

Anyway, here is the code...

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color: #000;
margin:0;
text-align:center;
min-width:1080px;
max-width:1200px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
font:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#FFF;
}
ul#navigation {
position: fixed;
z-index:9999;
background-color:#999;
margin:0;
width:0px;
}
ul#navigation li {
text-align:left;
list-style:none;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script>

$(function() {

            $("ul#navigation").hover(function(){
                    $('ul#navigation').stop().animate({'width':'150px'},200);
                },
                function () {
                    $('ul#navigation').stop().animate({'width':'0px'},200);
                }
            );
        });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="navigation">
<li>Home</li>
<li>About</li>
<li>Pics</li>
<li>Stuff</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: provide an example with jsfiddle.net

Comment: seems hard to fire a mouseover event for not visible elements. But for sure there are some workarounds

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sUm2W/

Example as requested. As you can see the lines are shown at the beginning and it takes a hover to get rid of them. From then on the menu functions as it should (other than I have no idea where the 40px margin comes from).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood all, but a simple
`$("ul#navigation").hide()` and `$("ul#navigation").show()` can work, no?

Comment: Sorry I understand this. I knew it would be difficult to get my question across.

When the page loads the menu should be at its smallest, the lines should be hidden (li's) but they aren't. I have now added an example to show what I mean.

Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 0):

Your jquery function is responsible for this effect. On hover it is animating width (i.e. changing width slowly)

```
 $("ul#navigation").hover(function(){
                $('ul#navigation').stop().animate({'width':'150px'},200);
            },
            function () {
                $('ul#navigation').stop().animate({'width':'0px'},200);
            }
        );
```

Comment: Sorry I understand this. I knew it would be difficult to get my question across.

When the page loads the menu should be at its smallest, the lines should be hidden (li's) but they aren't. I have now added an example to show what I mean.

Thanks for your reply :)

Comment: Firstly regarding the 40px margin it comes by default for all unordered list items. you can consider replacing ul/li tags with dl/dt tags(see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_dl.asp). This will remove 40px issue. Next regarding display list items on launch. I believe keeping width: 0 will not hide them. i would recommend to keep ur list in a div tag and keep display:none for div. but to make them visible again atleast show some sign like + or menu on which if mouse hover happens fire some jquery code to display again. Not sure if u can fire event on items which are not visible.